# Fixing a broken "chain of trust" in Windows 7 Certificates?

Tags: windows-7, certificate

I [was told](https://superuser.com/questions/464214/where-do-i-find-the-certificate-file-so-i-can-add-a-program-to-trusted-publishe) that "The Chain of Trust" was broken on this certificate for my malware scanner "Webroot".

How do I fix "The Chain of Trust"?
("The Chain of Trust" sounds like a botched version of something out of the Meet the Parents line of films...)

The "Key Usage" is apparently the problem, but I'm not sure what to do...in earlier versions of Windows you just ran programs that you pulled off of the Internet (which admittedly probably wasn't a real good idea...), but I also don't have even the smallest clue of how to fix this or where to start reading about it....

[image: The Chain of Trust is Broken]

And here is the chain I guess...

[image: this is the chain of trust, maybe?]

Comment: Anybody have a little more insight into this one yet?

Answer (score 1):

The key usage certificate extension, just defines what the certificate is used for. I highly doubt this is the error, i would rather think that error means you are missing a certificate further up in the chain, possibly even a Tusted Root CA certificate. Switch to the certification path tab and upload a screenshot :)

Edit: You were led on a wild goose chase, it looks like what you trying to do requires self-signed the exe files, you can read up on about that on MSDN: [Step 8: Authenticode Signature (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756995.aspx)

Comment: I click all of them on the way up and it says that the certificates are okay....more specifically "This certificate is OK".

Comment: Ok that guy just made stuff up, so what you really trying to do is stop a signed exe from showing a UAC dialog

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do...it comes up every time I start Windows and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: It also says that the 1024-bit ones should only be used for testing it says...